# Merge [schtasks] into [schtasks.exe]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[schtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) --> [schtasks.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks.exe)

They both refer to `schtasks.exe`, a command-line scheduled task management tool in Windows.

[schtasks.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks.exe) has more question tagged, and a significantly more detailed tag wiki, so it's the better candidate for the merge destination (merge result).

I propose merging [schtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) into [schtasks.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks.exe), and make the former a synonym of the latter.

Comment: This question has some shtick for [schtasks]

Answer (score 5):

I cannot think of any reason these should be separate from [windows-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-scheduler), and I suggest that this one is the best named of the three.

They should be synonymized, but we need to go through [schtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/schtasks) to make sure they're all Windows related. At first glance, it appears this is the case. If any are not, they need to be retagged to the related [scheduled-tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheduled-tasks).

Comment: Yes. Both are 100% Windows so it's fine to merge.

Comment: I oppose involving [tag:scheduled-tasks]. A quick lookup suggests there are other platforms/languages that use this concept. Example: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48222167), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48447878/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48403939).

Comment: @iBug [tag:scheduled-tasks] would only be appropriate if a question was abusing [tag:schtasks] to mean scheduled tasks in general, as opposed to working with the Windows scheduler technology. However, since you've confirmed this is not the case, there's no need to involve it.

Comment: Yes. And hopefully [tag:schtasks] has not been abused by far.

Comment: But hey, there are ways to modify Windows Scheduled Tasks programatically by calling Windows APIs, without touching `schtasks.exe`. Also, [tag:schtasks.exe] has a very comprehensive tag wiki. It is worth thinking twice before merging into [tag:windows-scheduler].